# why don't the memcpy and sprintf work in this kernel code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

why do the `memcpy` and `sprintf` in the following code are failed in kernel code?

```
static inline void my_func(){
    char* src,dst;
    int a =9; int b=10;

    src = sprintf("a= %d b= %d",a,b); 
    dst = kmalloc(strlen(src)*sizeof(char) , GFP_KERNEL);
    memcpy(dst, src, strlen(src));
}
```

Comment: Those of you said it is not in the kernel. try grep the kernel and see sprintf.... e.g.:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/s390/net/ctcm_sysfs.c?v=2.6.32

Comment: Please rework your question title. this one makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sprintf prints in to a char array. Hence the correct usage would be,

```
char src [MAX_CHARS];
sprintf(src, "a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
```

Alternatively, you could use `char *src` and allocate memory to `src` prior to calling sprintf.

The declaration for dest should be,

```
char *src, *dest;
```

Another issue to be aware of is that in `memcpy(dst, src, strlen(src))`, the strlen returns the length of the string without the terminating null character. Hence, if you want to copy the entire string along with the null character, you will have to add 1 to the value returned by `strlen` function.

```
dest = malloc( strlen(src) + 1 );
memcpy( dest, src, strlen(src) + 1 );
```

Comment: sprintf is a libc function not available in the kernel

Comment: @AdrianCornish, True, but it looks like like 0x90 is learning allocation, string, sprintf...

Comment: @AdrianCornish `sprintf` is defined in `lib/vsprintf.c`.

Comment: @shr and why does that have any relevance to his question that these function are not available in the kernel - they are not there full stop.

Comment: @cnicutar Right and in kernel code which does not have libc - please tell me where they are defined?

Comment: @AdrianCornish lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/vsprintf.c

Answer (score 1):

You could use kmalloc,kfree,ksnprintf -

Comment: There's no function called `ksnprintf`

Answer (score 0):

Because neither exist in kernel programming.

libc functions are not available to the kernel simply because they then tie the kernel to a language standard - and also some of them are just plain efficient for kernel use. 
Arvind has provided the kernel equivalents.

Comment: The kernel isn't linked with libc but identically-named functions exist.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=snprintf http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=memcpy

Answer (score 0):

kernel C library and libc both are dofferent. Avoid using libc function in kernel modules. And here sprintf is under libc.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other coding issues you have there, use snprintf() and kmemdup().